# Glassfish v3 shuts down after logging off user from Windows server 2003

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3

The glassfish server v3 is getting shutdown whenever i log off from my server and after searching on internet i added

```
<jvm-options>-Xrs</jvm-options>
```

line at in domain.xml file .The problem yet persists .Please help !!

Comment: Check this https://blogs.oracle.com/foo/entry/how_to_make_v3_platform

Comment: @Gas Tried this too.Not worked for me. I am getting mad abt what to do

Comment: Did you defined it as service and are you starting it through Windows Services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made below changes and got my result after so many days of hunt

1. added -Xrs in domain.xml file
2. added -Xrs in asadmin.bat file at install-dir/bin/asadmin.bat
3. created service through asadmin command "create-service"
4. [Implemented steps given in this link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Figordcard.blogspot.com%2F2012%2F03%2Frun-glassfish-as-service-on-windows.html&ei=zGrWU6PNGYq8uATn4IKIBQ&usg=AFQjCNGj-mBhZRZhseZgOLtyD1ktsECxmg&bvm=bv.71778758,d.c2E)

And bingo !! i got it